# Date to XMLGregorianCalendar separator comma instead of dot

Tags: java, xml, date, converters

I have the following problem:

I have converted a `java.util.Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar` and the output has the following format:

```
2016-03-15T20:43:45.776+01:00
```

Instead I need:

```
2015-10-31T14:35:01,905+01:00
```

So any suggestions on how to change the `.` into `,` programmtically?
String replace is not an option because I need to pass the `XMLGregorianCalendar` object further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although using comma is the officially preferred style in ISO-8601-paper, XML-schema has deviated from this and only uses dot. It is even mandated, and `XMLGregorianCalendar` primarily follows XML-schema, not ISO-8601, so I think there is no way for what you want to realize.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The ISO 8601 ist actually in the requirement for the webservice operation we will deliver but we are first to check this. I will ask them if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The **ISO-8601**-paper makes following statement:

> 4.2.2.4 Representations with decimal fraction
>
> [...]If a decimal fraction is included, lower order time elements (if any)
>   shall be omitted and the decimal fraction shall be divided from the
>   integer part by the decimal sign specified in ISO 31-0, i.e. the comma
>   [,] or full stop [.]. Of these, the comma is the preferred sign.[...]

But **XML-Schema** says (as deviation) that only the dot is allowed in any lexical representation of its built-in time-related types (for example: xs:datetime or [xs:time](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#nt-eodFrag)). And the Java-class `XMLGregorianCalendar` only models the built-in types so not permitting the comma as decimal sign. This statement is also backed by the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar-java.lang.String-) of the method `DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String lexicalRepresentation)` which points to the appropriate location in XML-Schema 1.0.

So if your webservice requires the comma (but it should also be able to process a dot according to ISO-8601) then you cannot use `XMLGregorianCalendar` but have to use your own solution and probably custom user types in XML. **Personally I think that the dot should be possible.**

Comment: Thanks again for clearing things out. Our framework uses XMLGregorianCalendar in its core so it would be too expensive to patch only for one operation. Instead we contacted the specification team and told them we deliver "the dot" or nothing (the attribute is not mandatory).
And you are right - if the receiving part implements ISO 8601 they SHOULD be able to read it.